# How can we use GEOLOQI  for iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, ios, geolocation

The following URL https://developers.geoloqi.com/account/applications/new

asks

1. Name,Description,image,Redirect URI etc.
2. P12 Certificate,P12 Password ,APNS Mode.

Can anyone explain  why should we give  Name,Description,image etc?
What p12 certificate,-12 Password,APNS Mode I have to give?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **name, description** and **image** are used internally so we know what apps are using the API. They will also be used to potentially feature apps on a "gallery" page of apps using our API.

The **redirect URI** is only needed if you are making an app that will be used by users of our [Geoloqi app](https://geoloqi.com/app), where the users will need to use OAuth to authorize your application to their account.

The **P12 certificate and password** are needed if you are making an iPhone app and wish to use Geoloqi to send push notifications through your app.